# how to write if statement in fixed password value in react yup

Tags: reactjs

const initialValues = {
email: '',
password: '',
remember: false
}

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('invalid mail id').required("Required"),
    password: Yup.string().required("Required")

    
})
const onSubmit = (values, props) => {
    console.log(values)
    setTimeout(() => {
        props.resetForm()
        props.setSubmitting(false)
    }, 2000)
```

this is the code.if fix a password value it will show success. if i give another password it will show incorrect password.how to write the code in yup

Answer (score 0):

yup’s `test` function helps find a solution. It’s documented like this:

```
mixed.test(name: string, message: string, test: function)
```

And for your particular case you could try this:

```
const pass = 's0m3t3xt';
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().email('invalid mail id').required("Required"),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .test('match', 
      'wrong password', 
       function(password) { 
         return password === pass; 
       }),
}),
```